# Using Mod_Rewrite With Image URL Parameters

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using a script to watermark images on the fly through a URL.

For example: `http://example.com/watermark.php?filename=assets/img/temp/temp_share.jpg` would result in `temp_share.jpg` having a watermark on the new image.

I'm trying to use `mod_rewrite` to clean up the URL to something like `http://example.com/filename/assets/img/temp/temp_share.jpg`

I used the generator at [this site](http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php) and it gave me `RewriteRule ^filename/([^/]*)$ /watermark.php?filename=$1 [L]`.

But when I try to go to `http://example.com/filename/assets/img/temp/temp_share.jpg` I get an error of `Not Found The requested URL /filename/assets/img/temp/temp_share.jpg was not found on this server.`

I'm not sure what I've done wrong.

Full contents of my .htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 400 /err.php?err=400
ErrorDocument 401 /err.php?err=401
ErrorDocument 403 /err.php?err=403
ErrorDocument 404 /err.php?err=404
ErrorDocument 500 /err.php?err=500
ErrorDocument 502 /err.php?err=502
ErrorDocument 504 /err.php?err=504

Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule assets/styles/style.css assets/styles/style.php [L]
RewriteRule assets/styles/m.style.css assets/styles/m.style.php [L]

RewriteRule ^filename/([^/]*)$ /watermark.php?filename=$1 [L]

<FilesMatch ".(jpg|png|gif|jpeg)$">
ErrorDocument 404 error/stormtrooperBrokenImage.jpg
</FilesMatch>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin http://lucycypher.com  
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
</IfModule>
```

Contents of `watermark.php`:

```
$imgpath=$_REQUEST['filename'];
header('content-type: image/jpeg'); 
$watermarkfile="assets/img/logo_variations/logo_watermark_75.png";
$watermark = imagecreatefrompng($watermarkfile);
list($watermark_width,$watermark_height) = getimagesize($watermarkfile);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgpath);
$size = getimagesize($imgpath);
$dest_x = ($size[0] - $watermark_width)/2;
$dest_y = ($size[1] - $watermark_height)/2;
imagecopy($image, $watermark, $dest_x, $dest_y, 0, 0, $watermark_width, $watermark_height);
imagejpeg($image);
imagedestroy($image);
imagedestroy($watermark);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[^/]` is a character class of all characters **except for** /

Since your file names do contain / you need to capture all characters after the "filename/" token.  Try changing it to this.

```
RewriteRule ^filename/(.*)$ /watermark.php?filename=$1 [L]
```

After tripple checking that your rewrite module is enabled and you have done a server restart, if it still doesn't work you should consider enabling verbose rewrite debugging to log files.

You should also consider adding an extra security check on the image path.  It is very easy for somebody to manipulate the filename param with things like `../../../sensitive_uploads/1.jpg` to navigate to somewhere outside of your image directory.

Comment: I see. So if I understand correctly if I were to put `[^a]` then that would be a character class for all characters except for `a`?

Comment: Exactly.  There's more info [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html#regex)  See Negative Character Class.